# Updating UITableView after download is finished/started

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm dealing with a tricky situation in my app. This app shows a list of files in a UITableView, from there you can download (I use AFnetworking 2.0) a file and then you can see download progress in another UITableView (all the views are in a UITabBarController).

My problem is that I'm not really sure about how to reload the UITableVIew showing current downloads when a new one is added or when one is finished or cancelled. I tried using KVO but it didn't work observing the operation queue from AFnetworking.

**EDIT:**
This is the KVO code I tried

In my downloads UITableViewCell

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

[[[[PodcastManager sharedManager] sessionManager] operationQueue] addObserver:self
                                                                 forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(operations))
                                                                    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                                                    context:nil];
 }
```

and then...

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
  if (object == [[[PodcastManager sharedManager] sessionManager] operationQueue]) {

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(operations))]) {

      NSLog(@"OperationCount: %lu", (unsigned long)[[[[[PodcastManager sharedManager] sessionManager] operationQueue] operations] count] );

    }
  }
}
```

But this "solution" didn't work here.

In the past, I faced a similar situation with another app and then I used blocks, but this time, I want to avoid that solution because there is some part of my current app's code I want to reuse in the future.

Anybody has faced a similar situation can bring some light?

Thank you.

Comment: post code you tried it

Comment: Done, that's my KVO code right now.

Comment: That's not my answer, that's the code I tried and didn't work.

Comment: Qn : how using blocks avoiding from reusing the code?

Comment: @LithuT.V Right now I'm thinking more deeply in the blocks solution and seems the best solution so far. I don't like blocks abusing, I think they produce a non clear code... it's just my opinion xD. I'll think again and make some tests around blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just run

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

after each download? Maybe I"m missing something. But that's what I'd do.